# NSUrlSessionDataDelegate: Most methods don't get called

Tags: iis, xamarin.ios, nsurlsession

yesterday I wanted to implement the DidReceiveData method to my NSUrlSessionDataDelegate. I noticed that the DidReceiveData method never gets called, and while I tried to track down the error I noticed that the other methods don't get called either. I'm pretty sure that the other methods worked before, I don't know if I changed something or maybe a Xamarin.iOS update is the cause, but maybe I am wrong here and they never worked.
I can confirm this problem for the methods DidReceiveResponse, DidReceiveData, and DidCompleteWithError.

Here is the code that creates the NSUrlSession and handles the response (note: I call IIS WebMethods that answer in XML):

```
           public async Task<string> Invoke(string sUrl)
    {
        session = NSUrlSession.FromConfiguration(NSUrlSessionConfiguration.DefaultSessionConfiguration, 
                                                 (INSUrlSessionDelegate)new SessionDelegate((x)=> _fehlermeldung = x),  // Übergebe Methode damit der SessionDelegate die Fehlermeldung weiterreichen kann
                                                 null);
        request = CreateGETRequest(CreateNSUrl(sUrl));

        var data = session.CreateDataTaskAsync(request, out dataTask);
        dataTask.Resume();
        NSUrlSessionDataTaskRequest response = null;
        try
        {
            response = await data;
        }
        catch (NSErrorException ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Error.LocalizedDescription + ": " + _fehlermeldung);
        }
        var doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml(response.Data.ToString());
        XmlNode elem = doc.DocumentElement.FirstChild;

        return elem.InnerText;
    }

    private NSUrl CreateNSUrl(string url)
    {
        string converted = ((NSString)url).CreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NSStringEncoding.UTF8);
        var nsurl = NSUrl.FromString(converted);

        if (nsurl == null)
            throw new Exception("Fehlerhafte URL: Aus '" + url + "' konnte kein gültiges NSUrl Objekt erzeugt werden.");

        return nsurl;
    }

    private NSMutableUrlRequest CreateGETRequest(NSUrl nsurl)
    {
        return new NSMutableUrlRequest(nsurl) { HttpMethod = "GET" };
    }
```

And here is my implementation of the session delegate:

```
    private class SessionDelegate : NSUrlSessionDataDelegate,  INSUrlSessionDelegate
    {
        private readonly Action<string> setFehler;
        public SessionDelegate(Action<string> setFehler)
        {
            this.setFehler = setFehler;
        }

        public override void DidReceiveResponse(NSUrlSession session, NSUrlSessionDataTask dataTask, NSUrlResponse response, Action<NSUrlSessionResponseDisposition> completionHandler)
        {
            var http_response = response as NSHttpUrlResponse;
            if (http_response == null)
            {
                setFehler($"Keine HTTP Url Antwort erhalten: {Environment.NewLine}'{response}'");
                completionHandler(NSUrlSessionResponseDisposition.Cancel);
                return;
            }

            var status_code = (int)http_response.StatusCode;
            if (status_code == 200) 
            {
                completionHandler(NSUrlSessionResponseDisposition.Allow);
            }
            else
            {
                setFehler($"Verbindung abgewiesen, HTTP Status: { status_code}, '{ http_response.ToString()}'");
                completionHandler(NSUrlSessionResponseDisposition.Cancel);
            }
        }

        public override void DidReceiveData(NSUrlSession session, NSUrlSessionDataTask dataTask, NSData data)
        {
            // THIS DOES NOT GET CALLED :-(
        }

        public override void DidCompleteWithError(NSUrlSession session, NSUrlSessionTask task, NSError error)
        {
            if (error != null)
            {
                task.Cancel();
                var ex = new NSErrorException(error);
                throw (ex);
            }
        }

        public override void DidReceiveChallenge(NSUrlSession session, NSUrlSessionTask task, NSUrlAuthenticationChallenge challenge, Action<NSUrlSessionAuthChallengeDisposition, NSUrlCredential> completionHandler)
        {
            [...] // This is working fine for Client Cert Authentication or Basic Authentication
        }
    }
```

The DidReceiveChallenge method does get called and is working. I cut it out for readability. 
All the other methods don't get called. I would like to know what I am doing wrong. You can find the same questions from native iOS users, but I can't figure out how to implement their solutions with Xamarin.iOS.

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: can you provide the environment of network? And the version of VS. I do the similar step as you did but it is fine

Comment: I'm working on Windows 10 with Visual Studio 2017, Version 15.8.1. Not sure what you mean with network environment? The IIS runs on version 2012 running on a HyperV. The connection is established via internet or lan. I will try if the methods get called when I run this directly on the MacBook. I recently switched from programming on a MacBook to Windows with a MacMini as the build machine for iOS, maybe thats the problem.

Comment: Have you solve the problem?

Comment: Nope :( Just tested the same code on my mac. The methods never get called. It doesn't matter what I do inside them, I can just uncomment all the code and still everything works...